# Can't fix return type on Async

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, geolocation, async-await

I am currently stuck with this issue and this error:

- the issue: I can't figure out how to fix the error I am getting, even if I read documentation about it on Google searches etc. Really, don't tell me to do that again, I don't get how to do it!
- the error: the return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task
- the code:

> ```
> private async Geoposition userLocation()
>     {
>     Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
>     geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;
>     try
>     {
>         Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(maximumAge:TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),timeout:TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
>         return geoposition;
>     }
>     catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
>     {
>         return null;
>     }
>     return null;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what the issue is. Your method must be `void`, `Task`, or `Task<T>`.

Change your method signature to:

```
private async Task<Geoposition> userLocation() { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually didn't know I could return a value like that. That Task notation was unknown to me  :)

Comment: What I can't now understand is how to read the returned value from the function calling it. I can't just make a Geoposition position variable, it says me it cannot be converted from Task. How would you do that?

Comment: That's fine, I fixed it by making:  Geoposition currentPosition = await userLocation(); I added the await and it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

As the error is trying to say to you: you need to change the return type of your function to task so it will look like this:

```
private async Task<Geoposition> userLocation
```

Answer (score 2):

As you're using `async`, you should return a `Task`, `Task<T>` or `void`.

```
private async Task<Geoposition> userLocation()
{
    //Do something here
}
```

You can check [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx) about async returns type